# Date, substraction, conditions and rendering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date

I'm currently trying to create a method that will substract two dates.
Here's what it looks like : (maturity is a futur time)

```
  def time_remaining
    # If validated, return time between now and number of days from validation.
    if self.is_validated?
      return (self.maturity > Time.now) ? (self.maturity - Time.now) : 0
    # If not validated, return number of days converted in time
    else
      return self.nb_days.nil? ? 0 : self.nb_days.days
    end
  end
```

And in my View my doing this :

```
distance_of_time_in_words(project.time_remaining)
```

This works but it isn't what I'm really trying to do, what I want is to retrieve a number of hours if the result of the substraction equals less than a day, to retrieve a number of minutes if the result of the substraction equals less than an hour and to retrieve a number of days if the result equals more than a day.

maturity is under this format : `Wed, 27 Nov 2013 12:42:09 UTC +00:00`.
Can you please tell me at least a hint about how can I do that ?

**EDIT :**

I've tried something like this but it's really messy :

```
def time_remaining
    # If validated, return time between now and number of days from validation.
    if self.is_validated?
      if (self.maturity > Time.now)
        if ((self.maturity - Time.now)/1.day < 1)
          return (self.maturity - Time.now)/1.day.
        elsif ((self.maturity - Time.now) < 1.hour)
          return (self.maturity - Time.now)/1.min
        else
          return (self.maturity - Time.now)
        end
      else
        0
      end
    # If not validated, return number of days converted in time
    else
      return self.nb_days.nil? ? 0 : self.nb_days.days
    end
  end
```

The point is to remove the `distance_of_time_in_words` here.

**Solution :** Thanks to @Rafał Cieślak and the gem time_diff.
Here's what I've done :

```
  def remaining_time (project)
    if project.is_validated?
      if ((project.maturity - Time.now)/1.day >= 1)
        result = Time.diff(project.maturity, Time.now, '%d')
        return result[:diff]
      elsif ((project.maturity - Time.now)/1.hour > 1 && (project.maturity - Time.now)/1.hour < 24)
        result = Time.diff(project.maturity, Time.now, '%H')
        return result[:diff]
      elsif ((project.maturity - Time.now)/1.hour < 1)
        result = Time.diff(project.maturity, Time.now, '%N')
        return result[:diff]
      end
    else
      return project.nb_days.nil? ? 0 : project.nb_days.days
    end
  end
```

Comment: you have to at least show some code of what you've tried.

Comment: done. But it's kind of messy :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is something I hacked really quick. You'll need to install [time_diff](https://github.com/abhidsm/time_diff) gem and use the following method as a helper (not in your model).

```
def time_remaining(time_start, time_end)
  diff_hash = Time.diff(time_start, time_end)
  diff_hash.delete :diff
  output = []

  diff_hash.each do |key, value|
    output.push(pluralize(value, key.to_s)) if value > 0
  end

  output.join(', ')
end
```

Examples:

```
>> time_remaining 2.days.ago.change(min: 58, hour: 15), Time.now
=> "1 day, 20 hours, 19 minutes, 24 seconds"
>> time_remaining 34.minutes.ago.change(sec: 15), Time.now
=> "33 minutes, 53 seconds"
```

Comment: The gem looks pretty nice, I'll try it asap and tell you if it worked !

Comment: It should work just fine in the view as a helper. However, if you want to store that data in the database or use it in a model, I don't really think there's a need to do it there, as models and the database aren't presentation layer. If you really need to store the time difference info somewhere, you can store it in a hash form that Time.diff returns.